# Set the visibility for a process window

Tags: c#

To check if a window is visibile i have to use:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
```

But how do i change the visiblity?
True/False

EDIT:

Hiding works:

```
            Process P;
            P = Process.GetProcessesByName("javaw")[2];
            ShowWindow(P.MainWindowHandle, 0);
```

But showing does not:

```
            Process P;
            P = Process.GetProcessesByName("javaw")[2];
            ShowWindow(P.MainWindowHandle, 5);
```

EDIT:

```
            ShowWindow(FindWindow(null, "WINDOWNAME"), 0);
```

0 invisibvle
5 visible

WORKS

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, ShowWindowCommands nCmdShow);
```

Comment: What about `SW_SHOWNORMAL` (1)? It should work; it is the right way to show/hide/minimise/maximise etc windows in the Windows API and if it's not working then you're doing something wrong.